# Fancybox and DNN DotNetNuke

Tags: jquery, fancybox

How do you install Fancybox into DotNetNuke? 
I am running a website that used DNN 6.2 and need to iframe content into a lightbox. Fancybox seems like the best optioon, but how to install it? Do you upload the files into the skin's folder or into the root folder of the site?

Answer (score 0):

I have incorporated fancybox in my skin.
Steps: 
1. you make sure the js and the css are loaded by the page onto which you want to use fancy box.
2. define the anchor to be used to fire fancybox, in this case I also made the size of the fancybox dynamic so the content manager can change it.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery('a.mylightbox').each(function () {
        var dWidth = parseInt($(this).attr('href').match(/width=[0-9]+/i)[0].replace('width=', ''));
        var dHeight = parseInt($(this).attr('href').match(/height=[0-9]+/i)[0].replace('height=', ''));
        $(this).fancybox({
        'width': dWidth,
        'height': dHeight,
        'autoScale': false,
        'transitionIn': 'elastic',
        'transitionOut': 'elastic',
        'type': 'iframe',
        'scrolling': 'no'
        });
    });
});
```

Next you call the url which you want to load in the fancybox:

```
<a class="mylightbox" href="/tabid/333/default.aspx?width=440&amp;height=650">my link text</a>
```

In this case I used a local page in my site.

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is a bit late :-)

DNN has the possibility (since DNN 7.2) to package JavaScript libraries, and then load them in the code, either by

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="JavaScriptLibraryInclude" Src="~/admin/Skins/JavaScriptLibraryInclude.ascx" %>
[...]
<dnn:JavaScriptLibraryInclude runat="server" Name="FancyBox" />
```

in the ascx, or

```
JavaScript.RequestRegistration("FancyBox")
```

in the C#-code behind.

First you have to create a package for the JavaScript library, which is quite easy to do. For references see https://github.com/EngageSoftware/DNN-JavaScript-Libraries (if you find the package needed there, you can use it, but I did not see FancyBox).

For further information see https://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/javascript-libraries

Happy DNNing!
Michael